# Включение 'Миграции сборок Django' в меню проекта Visual Studio 2017

Tags: django, visual-studio-2017

После выполнения некорректных миграций в проекте Django и ответа на вопрос оболочки о выборе продолжения действий стал недоступен пункт 'Миграции сборок Django' , как его включить/активизировать снова?[image: Vеню миграций сборок Django]

Comment: Эм, даже не знаю. Я бы посоветовал сделать миграции вручную. Я для себя писал небольшой бат-файл, который выполнял всю работу. Если по студии - попробуйте сделать просто миграции, перезагрузить студию. Еще он может быть не активным, если считает, что нет никаких изменений в моделях. Как вариант - попробовать удалить файлы миграций

Comment: Да, пункт выполнения миграций был недоступен из-за отсутствия новых изменений в моделях. После преобразования моделей эта опция снова стала активной в меню!